# What does an open bracket signify when using Alamofire to inspect a server response?

Tags: swift, http-headers, alamofire, http-status-code-400

[image]

When making a call using Alamofire, I'd like to inspect the response from the server.  The server response with `{ status code 400, Headers {`
but doesn't show the rest of the information.  What does this mean?  I have a high inclination that the problem is with my headers but I'm not sure what it is specifically.

```
class func missionOne(){

        let authorizationPath: String = "https://belivedev.restv2.eastus.media.azure.net/api/Channels"
        if let authorizationURL: URL = URL.init(string: authorizationPath){
            let parameters: [String : Any] = [
                "Name": "iOS-test-channel-1",
                "Description": "My channel description for use in discovery",
                "Input": [
                    "KeyFrameInterval": "",
                    "StreamingProtocol": "FragmentedMP4",
                    "AccessControl": ["IP": ["Allow": [
                        [
                            "Name": "Allow All",
                            "Address": "0.0.0.0",
                            "SubnetPrefixLength": ""
                        ]
                        ]]],
                    "Endpoints": []
                ],
                "Preview": [
                    "AccessControl": ["IP": ["Allow": [
                        [
                            "Name": "Allow All",
                            "Address": "0.0.0.0",
                            "SubnetPrefixLength": ""
                        ]
                        ]]],
                    "Endpoints": []
                ],
                "Output": ["Hls": ["FragmentsPerSegment": 1]],
                "CrossSiteAccessPolicies": [
                    "ClientAccessPolicy": "",
                    "CrossDomainPolicy": ""
                ]
            ]
            guard let bearerToken = AzureMediaServicesAPIManager.sharedInstance.authToken else { return }
            let headers = [
                "x-ms-version": "2.15",
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "DataServiceVersion": "3.0",
                "MaxDataServiceVersion": "3.0",
                "User-Agent": "azure media services postman collection",
                "Authorization": "Bearer \(bearerToken)",
                "Host" : "https://rest.media.azure.net"
            ]
            Alamofire.request(authorizationURL, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
                .debugLog()
                .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
                .responseJSON { response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                        print("We hit the failure switch statement \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        print("The url request sent to the server is: \(response.request)")
                        print("The response sent back from the server is: \(response.response)")
                        return
                    case .success:
                        print("Validation Successful")
                        }
                    }
            }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter at the bottom of the console for `the response` is only showing the lines that contains that string. It looks the the `description` for that object contains new lines which are being hidden by the filter.

Remove the filter and scroll to the line in the console output, or do a find to search through the output.